# AddressBookUI like TableView for my application?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, addressbook

I've got a table-view with more than a thousand entries! That's just crazy, I know, but it makes no sense to split it into a tree. So what I'd like to do is to have an A-Z index and a search-bar just like in address book.

Is there such a framework around that lets me set my own datasource that has nothing to do with people and display it like in the address book?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table views with thousands of entries are fine, but you definitely want fast scrolling and searching.

For scrolling, implement the table view datasource methods [sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW5) and [tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW7).

For searching, add a [UISearchBar](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and implement some of its [delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate). You may also want to a [UISearchDisplayController](http://UISearchDisplayController) which lets you use your controller as the datasource/delegate for its separate search table view. It also has a [delegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Check out Apple's sample [TableSearch](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableSearch/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Index tabs are easy, just implement -sectionIndexTitlesForTableView: in your table view's datasource. It should return an array of strings, for example, A, B, C,...Z.

Answer (score 0):

Found a great answer here: http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=240

Short answer, use tableView:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    NSMutableArray *toBeReturned = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) [toBeReturned addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",c]];
    return toBeReturned;
}
```

Cheers

Nik